# Juniper Network Connect - don't disconnect Internet

Tags: networking, juniper

I'm using Juniper Network Connect to connect to a VPN. When I log in to the VPN it disconnects my other networks. I suspect this is a security feature, however I need to develop an application which is using both connections at the same time.

Are you aware of any method - a "right way" or even a "hack" which would allow me to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a security feature. If you're VPN'ed in, your IT department probably wants all traffic to go through their network (e.g. through anti-virus gateways, firewalls, etc). An attacker could theoretically compromise you remotely via the open internet, then hop through your VPN to access the corp net.

It is possible to configure the VPN server in a "split tunnel" mode which does exactly what you want. But this can only be enabled on the VPN gateway, not the client.